# IIS-hosted WCF service with net.tcp binding unreachable

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, net.tcp

I'm trying to host a WCF service with net.tcp binding within an IIS 7.5 site on Windows 7, 64-bit.  Sadly, the service is unreachable.  In fact, opening a connection to the TCP port using telnet even fails.

Here's what my system.serviceModel section of the web.config for the site looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2000000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehavior" 
               name="FooService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="service" 
                  name="service" contract="IFoo" />
        <endpoint binding="mexTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="DuplexBinding" contract="IFoo" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:9000/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="service" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                        maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="DuplexBinding">
          <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In IIS Manager, I set up a site with an App Pool running under the identity of NETWORK SERVICE, with the v4.0 .NET Framework and an integrated pipeline.  There is one binding for the site with a type of `net.tcp` and "Binding Information" set to `9000:*`.

Under my computer's services, I started the previously stopped "Net.Tcp Listener Adapter" and "Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service" services and made them both start up automatically.  I also ensured that "Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation" was installed.

What else do I have to do to get IIS/WCF/WAS/whatever to listen on port 9000 so my service can be activated and invoked?

*My question is similar to [Host WCF service with net.tcp binding through IIS Manager 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181011/host-wcf-service-with-net-tcp-binding-through-iis-manager-7-5), but the OP was not registered, and his question was not answered.  I'm opening this question so I can post my own details.*

**Update**

I've found some additional clues.  I decided to add a second binding so I can work with HTTP bindings while trying to figure out the net.tcp issues.  Now, when I try to access the HTTP endpoint, I get this error

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

I very clearly *have* bindings for both HTTP and net.tcp here:

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/"/>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8050/"/>
</baseAddresses>
```

So the phrase "Registered base address schemes" has me worried; is there something additional I have to do to allow my site to support the net.tcp scheme?

Comment: What URL are you trying from client ?

Comment: I've tried `net.tcp://127.0.0.1:9000/service` and other variations, but I figure if I cannot even establish a connection to port 9000, my problem doesn't lie in the URL.

Comment: try net.tcp://127.0.0.1:9000/service/service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got IIS to allow connections to port 9000.  I didn't see this option before, but I don't know if that's because I failed my spot check or if I had to do something to get it to show up.

Under the advanced settings of the IIS site, there is an "Enabled Protocols" setting.  Previously, it was set to just `http`.  After changing it to `http, net.tcp`, I can connect to the TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have done most things correctly.

The most probable issue that is left is the firewall. That the standard windows firewall is blocking port 9000.

Comment: I've created an inbound rule for the Windows 7 firewall for TCP port 9000, and the connection still fails.  Is there something else I need to do to bypass the firewall?

Comment: @Jacob - You can disable the firewall temporarily to be 100% sure that it's not the windows firewall.

Comment: Disabling the firewall is disallowed in my environment, unfortunately.  I think the error message I added to my question may be helpful in figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try SSamra's suggestion.  I think your base address and the URL you are trying are likely wrong.  Mine looks something like this:

net.tcp://localhost:PORT/ServiceNamespace/ClassName.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using IIS, I would drop the *baseAddress* node altogether as IIS will infer the base address from the bindings/virtual path you have configured.

Also keep in mind that WCF isn't going to be happy about the `httpGetEnabled="true"` attribute in your metadata behavior without any http endpoints available.